# Need suggestion on coding practices on the concept "Do Not Repeat Yourself"

Tags: java, oop, coding-style

I want to  get a better understanding of clean coding and OOP. I create for this instance a Chess Game.

Now, one of the basic principle is: "Do Not Repeat Yourself". Right now I can't figure out how I could create a Player Object which holds a list of ChessFigures without repeating myself in a createFigures() method.

In my logic a Player class holds at the beginning of every game 16 figures. Here I repeat myself 6 times. What would be the suggested algorithm in this case?

```
public class Player {

    private ArrayList<Figure> figures = new ArrayList<Figure>(16);
    private ColorEnum playerColor;

    Player(ColorEnum color){
        this.playerColor = color; 
        createFigures();
    }

    private void createFigures(){
        addFigure(8, PAWN);
        addFigure(2, KNIGHT);
        addFigure(2, BISHOP);
        addFigure(2, ROOK);
        addFigure(1, QUEEN);
        addFigure(1, KING);
    }

    private void addFigure(int amount, FigureTypeEnum type){
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            this.figures.add(new Figure(type, this.playerColor));
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Figure> getFigures() {
        return figures;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to get rid of the duplication you could add the count to the enum and interate over all enum values.

But I wouldn't see your code as a violation of the DRY principle as you only have one method and the calls all have different arguments. The code is very readable as it is.

A violation of the DRY principle would be if you have the same calls somewhere else, too.

Answer (score 1):

For a large part this is a matter of opinion, and I don't think there's much wrong with your current method. However, I think of the types and amounts of pieces as configuration and not as a part of the program. You could create a config file which defines the pieces available to each player. If for some reason the rules of chess change to include another piece, you would only need to alter the configuration and there's no need to figure out where in the source code this is defined.

In the actual case of chess this might be a bit overkill, but in a more general sense this seems like a clean solution.

Alternatively, you could use a `static final Map<FigureTypeEnum, Integer>` to hold the configuration, and fill it in a static initializer block. However, static initializer blocks aren't very common (at least in my experience) and might confuse junior developers.

Some other tips:

- Don't use the type witness in the initialization of the ArrayList. This should suffice: `private ArrayList<Figure> figures = new ArrayList<>();`
- I'm not sure about the initial size of the array list. It works in this case, because you know there are 16 pieces. But you create an implicit dependency between the createFigures and the initialization. Also, this seems like premature optimization.
- Consider defining the figures as a List instead of an ArrayList. Which List implementation is chosen seems to be irrelevant to your code.

EDIT:
One more consideration: If you return the actual list in the getFigures() method, you allow others to add or remove items from that list. That might not be desirable. You can use some immutable list (see for example: https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-list) or return a copy of the list.